# Is there a solution for following integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is it possible to solve the following integral?

$$\int\frac{\exp(-ax^2)}{x}\,dx.$$

Comment: This is basically the same question you asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068547/is-there-a-solution-for-this-exponential-integral).  Surely one of those answer can be applied to answer this question as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a solution for this exponential integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068547/is-there-a-solution-for-this-exponential-integral)

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $u=ax^2$:
$$\int\frac{\exp(-ax^2)}{x}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}\int-\frac{\exp(-u)}{u}\,dx=-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{E}_1(u)+C=-\frac{1}{2}\operatorname{E}_1(ax^2)+C$$